# Correcciones a Diagrama Físico Base de Datos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, diagrama-er

cree este post debido que me gustaría tener retroalimentación sobre mi diagrama físico de la base de datos que deseo hacer como un pequeño proyecto personal.

El proyecto consiste en hacer una base de datos con todas las instituciones educativas del país donde vivo, para tener una base donde se puedan ver todas la oferta academica de carreras universitarias y técnicas, cursos, especializaciones y maestrias.

Hice tablas pivotes porque me parece que todas las relaciones funcionan de muchos a muchos, por ejemplo, una institución educativa tiene muchas carreras, pero una carrera también está en muchas instituciones educativas; coloque las relaciones con las entidades cursos (entiendanse cursos, como formación continua, no como clases que se toman en la universidad), especializaciones y maestrias flexibles debido a que no toda universidad o tecnologico tiene maestrias o especializaciones. Agradezco de antemano por sus observaciones.

[image: Diagrama Físico Instituciones Educativas]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Simplemente es imposible darte feedback (mas alla que todo seria basado en opiniones) sin tener las reglas completas de negocios. Los nombres no alcanzan, hay que saber como es el negocio completo...

Comment: Solo necesitas una tabla para cursos, carreras, maestrías y especializaciones (u otros posgrados). Esa tabla requerirá de una columna (atributo) que defina que tipo de oferta educativa es. Por otro lado, las respuestas a preguntas de diseño van a variar según opiniones y posiblemente cerrarán tu pregunta.

Comment: @LuisCazares Muchas gracias por tu observación, ¿entonces unifico todas en una sola tabla y coloco un atributo que sea tipo de formacion donde se identifique si es carrera,curso, maestria u otra.?